# Using eth0 AND OR wlan0 independently

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

uname -a
Linux CamPan 4.4.50+ #970 Mon Feb 20 19:12:50 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

I have, after some struggles, managed to get BOTH wired (eth0) & wireless (wlan0) working on my Pi.

As per instructions here:

```
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address
```

I made one minor addition to `/etc/network/interfaces` , adding `auto wlan0` above

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`Supplicant.conf` looks like this:

```
    ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1
    country=GB

    network={
            ssid="XYZ"
            key_mgmt=NONE
    }

    network={
            ssid="ABC"
            psk="*****"
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    }

    network={
            ssid="DEF"
            psk="*****"
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    }

    network={
            ssid="GHI"
            psk="*****"
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

The last lines of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.7.220/24
static routers=192.168.7.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.7.1

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.7.221/24
static routers=192.168.7.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.7.1
```

Wireless connectivity works, providing eth0 is connected but if I reboot without a wired connection, the wireless isn't available.

The application is a Pi with an Adafruit stepper shield. It's running two stepper motors to control a stop-frame animation panning rig. I'm also learning how to create Python Restful APIs to control it, so I can control it via a web app (probably from my phone).

I need wireless for control and I need wired or wireless for setup, dev & test but it's a pain to have to connect wired for wireless. I could exclude the eth0 config and I presume that might work but it seems like an unnecessary hack. How can I have both `eth0` AND `wlan0`, independently

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? You have provided no status.

Comment: Because when I tried to ssh to or ping 192.168.7.121 or look on my router's 'connected devices' list or run nmap (from another network connected linux box), when eth0 isn't connected there's no sign of wlan0. Couldn't think of another way to test? Have I missed a trick?